# Store url in session and redirect to previous page after session expired

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I wondered how wordpress redirect users to the previous page they are working on after their session expire. I am trying to apply the same logic to my website.

I have searched online but couldn't get something. Here is the scenario, Let say I have My page links this way:

```html
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
    <i class="material-icons">account_box</i>
    <span>Tasks</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="ml-menu">
    <li><a href="change_pwd">Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="users">Add Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="wom">Worker of the Month</a></li>
    <li><a href="activities_logs">Activities Logs</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery">Upload Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs_ins">Post Vacancies</a></li>
    <li><a href="news">Create News</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How can I store this links to session so that when a user session expires and he log in again,he will be directed to the page he is working on  instead of dashboard?

Comment: If the session expires, the session expires. Are you sure this works by pure backend logic and not by storing something in an additional cookie?

Comment: @NicoHaase, you have a point. Even if it is in a cookie, I just want to know how to keep track of the previous page the user maybe after it session expires and logs out.

Comment: for that they check by ajax every 10 seconds